# Difference between `Run()` and `py_run` and the use of `try except` block in `b.py` in Pylint

Tags: python, python-3.x, lint, pylint

This is my code:

```
# uses Python3.7
# a.py

from pylint import lint as pl

pathvar = 'test.py'
pylint_opts = [pathvar]

pl.Run(pylint_opts)

print('New Text File Here')
```

This code gives me the correct output but doesn't execute anything after `Run` statement and hence doesn't execute the print statement. However, If i add a `try except` block in there it runs fine.

```
# uses Python3.7
# b.py

from pylint import lint as pl

try:
    pathvar = 'test.py'
    pylint_opts = [pathvar]
    pl.Run(pylint_opts)
except:
    pass

print('New Text File Here')
```

There is also another method to run pylint on a file from python program:

```
# uses Python3.7
# c.py

from pylint import epylint as lint

pathvar = 'test.py'
lint.py_run(pathvar)

print('New Text File Here')
```

This one executes the `py_run` and then prints the correct output.
I know you might suggest that I should use `c.py` as it already solves my problem of running pylint. But  `a.py` is more general and various arguments can also be passed apart from running the pylint file. Why `b.py` needs a `try except` block and `c.py` doesnt for the print command to execute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [Run](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/master/pylint/lint.py#L1489) class uses `sys.exit` in its `__init__` method. You can pass `do_exit=False` argument like `pl.Run(pylint_opts, do_exit=False)` to make `a.py` working as you wish: printing after running pylint.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Also can you explain the working of `b.py` because I placed the code in `try` and it worked fine. This program doesn't generate any error but it seems that it is responding to the `try except` block.

Comment: @rahulrachh `sys.exit` actually generates an error. To see what is happening in `try except` block you can do `except Exception as exc: print(exc)`. You will see something like SystemExit exception.

Comment: I did as you mentioned and I didn't got an error in the output. Instead the end of the  output read `Process finished with exit code 16` instead of `0`.

Comment: @rahulrachh sorry, you need to except `BaseException` instead of `Exception`.

Comment: I got it. `16` is a belongs to `SystemExit` subclass of `BaseException` class. Got the same output when used `SystemExit` instead of `BaseException`.